# Javascript checkboxes to show/hide overlays on main SharePoint calendar view

Tags: javascript, calendar

I've got a main Global calendar with Regional calendar overlays associated.  Currently, clicking the colored tabs will only redirect the user to the filtered calendar view associated with tab name.   What I'd like to accomplish is having a check box below each colored tab that would in turn respond the same way the Overlay filter page does (when clicking "Calendar" and then "Calendar Overlays" on the ribbon) without leaving the main calendar page.  I'm sure the page would have to refresh after each check box action, but it staying on the main Global calendar page after each refresh would be ideal.

[image: Region Tabs]

[image: Overlay Settings]

By default, I'd like for all boxes to be checked whenever the main Global calendar link is clicked.  Always start all in.

Since there are 10 calendars on this main Global calendar view, I want to give the user the option to compare two or more regions by navigating which check boxes they select.  Checking the box will show the overlay view on the main Global Calendar. Unchecking the box would hide the overlay view on the main Global Calendar.  All without having to be redirected to the Calendar Overlay Settings page.

I want to move the check boxes on the Calendar Overlay Settings page over to the main Global Calendar page below each colored tab.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 0):

I am having this issue as well. It looks like you can create a view for each different combination then link to them but this becomes impractical quickly. Using check boxes would make things much easier.